# Different template for subcategories

Tags: categories, hierarchical, template-hierarchy

I would like to have a different template for categories and subcategories
The categories template is set in categories.php
is it somehow possible to load the subcategories template from subcategories.php or something like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The template hierarchy has filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy) for all types of templates. Here we can use `category_template`, check if the current category has a parent, and load the `subcategory.php` file in that case:

```
function wpd_subcategory_template( $template ) {
    $cat = get_queried_object();
    if ( isset( $cat ) && $cat->category_parent ) {
        $template = locate_template( 'subcategory.php' );
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'category_template', 'wpd_subcategory_template' );
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what im looking for.
Where do i need to put the code?

Comment: In your theme's `functions.php` or [in a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Comment: you just need to substitute subcategory.php for the file you would like to become the parent template

Comment: @Djanym RE [your suggested edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/248625) to test `isset( $cat )` first: I do generally appreciate caution, but in what circumstances can category_template get called when get_queried_object() is null?

Answer (score 4):

I have edited your code to add more functionality. For cases where someone would want to have a different template for each child category. For example if you have categories ordered like this:

- continent

  - country

    - city

And you need a different template for city. First we look if city has a child, if not we call the template for city. The rest of code is to check if a category has a parent.

```
// Different template for subcategories
function wpd_subcategory_template( $template ) {
    $cat        = get_queried_object();
    $children   = get_terms( $cat->taxonomy, array(
        'parent'     => $cat->term_id,
        'hide_empty' => false
    ) );

    if( ! $children ) {
        $template = locate_template( 'category-country-city.php' );
    } elseif( 0 < $cat->category_parent ) {
        $template = locate_template( 'category-country.php' );
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'category_template', 'wpd_subcategory_template' );
```