# taxonomy - templates are not loading

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates, template-hierarchy

I have registered taxonomy:

```
$taxonomySetup = [
    'label' => __('Products catalog'),
    'has_archive' => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => __('catalog'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'with_front' => true
    ],
];
register_taxonomy('products', ['product'], $taxonomySetup);


add_action('init', 'addTaxonomiesToPages');
function addTaxonomiesToPages() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('products', 'product');
}
```

which is linked to CPT:

```
register_post_type('product', [
    'labels' => [
        // labels definitions
    ],
    'public'                => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-archive',
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'taxonomies'            => ['products'],
    'publicly_queryable'    => false,
    'rewrite' => [
        'pages' => true,
    ],
    'supports' => [
        // supported items
    ],
]);
```

Now I have categories (for this taxonomy) structure with results:

- `http://example.com/catalog` - **Not Found**
- `http://example.com/catalog/subcategory-1` - **taxonomy.php**
- `http://example.com/catalog/subcategory-1/subcategory-2` - **taxonomy.php**
- `http://example.com/catalog/subcategory-1/subcategory-2/subcategory-3` - **taxonomy.php**
- `http://example.com/catalog/subcategory-1/subcategory-2/subcategory-3/subcategory-4` - **taxonomy.php**

I have created many files for it:

- `taxonomy.php`
- `taxonomy-products.php`
- `taxonomy-product.php`
- `taxonomy-catalog.php`

Why it always loading base taxonomy template and for main catalog it rendering `404` error?

btw. How can I control which template should be loaded for subcategory (I'm talking about sub-level, not naming)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct template for subcategories/subterms. 
both will be accessible in `taxonomy.php` 
I didn't get what's your requirement to have a separate page for subcategories/subterms. 
but you can handle this on taxonomy.php

```
if( subcat ){
 // show sub category view
}elseif(parent) {
 // show parent category view 
}
```

or check this answer more related to your request 
[Different template for subcategories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247367/different-template-for-subcategories)

Comment: Now I want to know, why taxonomy not loading template for it, only base.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress provides archive pages for *taxonomy terms*, not for taxonomies. As `catalog` is the taxonomy slug `http://example.com/catalog` returning a 404 is the expected behaviour.

A work-around for this situation is to create a new page with the slug `catalog`, and then use the `page-catalog.php` template with a custom query and loop to suit your needs.

`http://example.com/product` may provide what you're looking for. This page would use `archive-product.php`.

As you have `rewrite` defined in your `register_taxonomoy` call you will need to flush rewrites for the new rules to take effect.

Comment: I have tried with `archive.php`, `archive-product.php`, `archive-products.php` and nothing, still 404. (I have set `has_archive` to `true` and 're-saved' permalinks)

Comment: Every time I'm going to `Settings > Permalinks` and I'm clicking `Save`.