# Creating a Sub Category Template

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm new to building wordpress themes, I would like to create a template for all sub categories.

I have category.php and I want that to be used for only upper level categories (which is working so that's sorted out)

I would like to create a separate template for sub categories of any parent, is there a specific name I should name it or do I have to write a function ?

Please let me know, I have been searching and haven't found anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved via: [Different template for subcategories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247367/different-template-for-subcategories)

basically I need to create another page and assign it in functions.php using category template filter.